# Change the style of kendo UI progress

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I am quite new to this HTML world. I am looking forward to change the default color and remove the gray background from kendo progress bar as shown in image below :

[image]

I need to remove the background and make it transparent as well as change the color of spinner to blue.
How can this be achieved ?

Comment: As far as I know the KendoUI loading animation is a gif. So it's not that straightforward to make your desired changes. But you can check the different themes, they do have different loading animations.

Comment: Yes you can override the default gif, with any custom gif via CSS. As the answer suggests. Detailed information can be found on the [KendoUI docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui#methods-progress)

Comment: Yes Thanks !!! was able to achieve this effect by changing background image..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved this way:

```
.k-loading-mask .k-loading-image {
  background-image: url('...custom.image.url.here...');
}
```

To remove loading image:

```
.k-loading-mask .k-loading-image {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Further more customizations can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui#methods-progress)

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the background url to a gif image and it works...